# merging a photo into clouds

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have two pictures:

(1) a pic of sky with clouds
(2) a pic of some patterns

I like to use (1) as basis, but want to fill clouds with the pattern in (2). How may I do this? I use Photoshop on windows.

If the color and boundary of clouds are easily distinguishable from the sky, it might be easy. But when such a distinction is not obvious, I got a problem. How may I solve this problem?

Comment: This falls more into the photoshop bucket than photography bucket. We try to avoid questions that have to do with image editing techniques, as we are primarily a photography and photographic editing site (photo editing being fixing up things like tone curve, white balance, exposure, red-eye, etc.) General image editing questions are probably better asked on SuperUser.com.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a similar principle as would be used when trying to [make a bottle transparent](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2359/21) and make the clouds in your image appear transparent -- you could then add your pattern behind so they'd show through.

In addition to the techniques on that link, you could create a blending mask based on the brightness of your base image.